# Swift Post request parameters without the double quote marks

Tags: swift, nsmutabledictionary, json-serialization

My current code looks like this and request httpBody I'm sending is also there

```
 let params: [String: Any] = [
        "user_id": defaults.object(forKey: "userID") as! Int,
        "opid": opid
    ]

    guard let url = URL(string: addOldPrescriptionURL) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("text/html; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
```

{"opid":["762"],"user_id":78}

But when I'm making the post request from PostMan using the parameters like 
**user_id: 78
opid: ["762"]** 
(without the double quotes) its working fine but mine is not working. Can anyone please help how can I remove those quotes from the request httpBody.

Comment: The double quotes are fine and required to indicate strings in JSON. Are you sure that `text/html` is the correct content type as you are going to send JSON?

Comment: yeah, cause when I'm using "application/json" its giving me 500 status code.

Comment: Postman actually has a code generation feature, which does support Swift as well. If you already have a request working from postman, but you're unsure about your own code, why not try the generated one first?

Comment: Try to set `application/json` for both `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers.

Comment: Okay I'm trying that. @vadian

Comment: didn't know that, checking that out @DávidPásztor

Comment: It did generate and worked perfectly. Thank you @DávidPásztor